# How to query an XDocument with LINQ when elements have a colon in their name?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to use LINQ to XML in an with the XDocument object.  How do you query the result element in the example below?

```
<serv:header>
   <serv:response>
      <serv:result>SUCCESS</serv:result>
      <serv:gsbStatus>PRIMARY</serv:gsbStatus>
   </serv:response>
</serv:header>
```

When I use a statement like this, I get the exception 'Additional information: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.'

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string value = doc.Descendants("serv:header").First().Descendants("serv:response").First().Descendants("serv:result").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`serv` in your XML is a *namespace prefix*. It has to be associated with some URI, that identifies the namespace. Look for an attribute like this in your XML:

```
xmlns:serv="..."
```

The value inside the quotes will be the namespace. Now, in your C# code, you use that URI to create an `XNamespace` object:

```
private static readonly XNamespace serv = "...";
```

And then you can use that in queries like this:

```
string value = doc
    .Descendants(serv + "header").First()
    .Descendants(serv + "response").First()
    .Descendants(serv + "result").First()
    .Value;
```

By the way, you should consider using `.Element()` rather than `.Descendants().First()`.

Comment: I was able to use `doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("serv")`

Comment: Trimming the fat in my implementation, I was able to create a simpler variable in my target method: `XNamespace xd = @"http://...";`

Answer (score 6):

That colon means that the XML is using [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).  Based on this [blogpost](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2008/05/linq-to-xml-namespaces-and-vb.html) someone posted about LINQ, XML, and namespaces, here's a version of your code that you might want to try.:

```
static XName serv(string name)
{
  return XNamespace.Get("<THE_NAMESPACE_URL>") + name;
}

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string value = doc.Descendants(serv("header")).First().Descendants(serv("response")).First().Descendants(serv("result")).First().Value;
```